# How to populate a new list by querying most recent files in old list c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm setting up a Console app to cycle through the servers within the network and gather their most recent backup dates. I have the loop for the server connections and populated a list of all the backup dates. I am now trying to order the backup files by CreationTime, select the most recent file, and add that into a new list.

Here I have a query ordering the files I want by creationTime, grouping them by server and then by Max CreationTime and selecting those items via slimQuery.

```
List<Inputs> slimList = new List<Inputs>();

var orderByDescendingResult = from items in initialList
                              where items.FileName == "*GuestHelper*"
                              orderby items.CreationTime descending
                              select items;

var srvGroup = initialList.GroupBy(a => (a.ServerName.ToString()));

var maxDategroup = initialList.GroupBy(b => (b.CreationTime.Max()));

var slimQuery = from items in orderByDescendingResult
                group srvGroup by maxDategroup into listItems
                select listItems;

var initialName = from PropertyData p in slimQuery
                  where p.Name == "FileName"
                  select p.Value;

var initialDate = from PropertyData p in slimQuery
                  where p.Name == "CreationDate"
                  select p.Value;

var initialSize = from PropertyData p in slimQuery
                  where p.Name == "FileSize"
                  select p.Value;

var initialSrvr = from PropertyData p in slimQuery
                  where p.Name == "ServerName"
                  select p.Value;

var fileInfo = new Inputs
{
    ServerName = initialSrvr.ToString(),
    FileName = initialName.ToString(),
    CreationTime = initialDate.ToString()
};

slimList.Add(fileInfo);
```

My queries are returning null thus nothing is being added to my new list. So why are they returning null and what can I do to change the result?

[Picture of Query and List Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqY2L.png)

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Why are my queries returning null?

Comment: They aren't... or, they shouldn't ...., maybe the have no elements, but that's different.

Answer (score 0):

All your results are of type `IEnumerable` or some equivalent.

So, `initialName`, `initialDate` and `initialSrvr` are collections of objects. This collection can contain 0, 1 or multiple items.

If you want to select the value of a single element, here is a way to do it:

```
var fileInfo = new Inputs
{
     ServerName = initialSrvr.FirstOrDefault(),
     FileName = initialName.FirstOrDefault(),
     CreationTime = initialDate.FirstOrDefault(),
};
```

Note: there are multiple ways to get the value you want; have a look at [linq](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).